# Troubleshooting: Inconsistent Action Alignment with ID in Laravel Database

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm creating a table to do validation, pending and reject, based on existing data in the database. but as I attached in the picture the button for validating is on the right. that should align with the data. how to solve this problem? because to be honest I have been confused for 2 days to solve this problem

```
        @foreach($projects as $project)
    <td>
                @if ($project->status == '0')
                    <button onClick="toggleStatus('{{$project->id}}')">Verifikasi</button>
                @elseif ($project->status == '1')
                    <button onClick="toggleStatus('{{$project->id}}')">Unverifikasi</button>
                @endif
                @if ($project->pending == '0')
                    <button onClick="pending('{{$project->id}}')">Pending</button>
                @elseif ($project->pending == '1')
                    <button onClick="pending('{{$project->id}}')">Unpending</button>
                @endif
                @if ($project->invalid == '0')
                    <button onClick="invalid('{{$project->id}}')">Invalid</button>
                @elseif ($project->invalid == '1')
                    <button onClick="invalid('{{$project->id}}')">Unvalid</button>
                @endif
    </td>
        @endforeach
```

and the javascript is like this

```
   <script>
function toggleStatus(project_id) {
    fetch("{{ route('projects.toggle') }}?project_id=" + project_id)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            document.querySelector("#project-status-" + project_id).innerHTML = response.status;
     })
}
function pending(project_id) {
    fetch("{{ route('projects.pending') }}?project_id=" + project_id)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            document.querySelector("#project-pending-" + project_id).innerHTML = response.pending;
     })
}
function invalid(project_id) {
    fetch("{{ route('projects.invalid') }}?project_id=" + project_id)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            document.querySelector("#project-invalid-" + project_id).innerHTML = response.invalid;
     })
}
</script>
```

[image]